# Insert to mysql database through Rawsql

Tags: python, django, rawsql

I want to perform custome sql query on mysql database table to store the record
.What is the way to perform insert query through rawsql.

I am using following model

```
class Student(models.Model):
    userid = models.CharField(db_column='UserId', primary_key=True, max_length=12)  # Field name made lowercase.
    firstname = models.CharField(db_column='FirstName', max_length=30)  # Field name made lowercase.
    middlename = models.CharField(db_column='MiddleName', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    lastname = models.CharField(db_column='LastName', max_length=30)  # Field name made lowercase.
    password = models.CharField(db_column='Password', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

and trying to insert values through raw method because want to store passwoed through `md5('')` provided by mysql:

```
st = Student.object.raw("Insert into Student values(%s,%s,%s,%s,md5(%s))",['ST1','Fname','Mname','Lname','Pwd']);
```

but i am not getting how to execute this.Is there any way ?

Comment: Not sure if `raw` does `INSERT`s, but you should read more here - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a simple example:

```
from django.db import connections

cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE(field1,field2) VALUES( %s , %s )", [value1, value2])
```